# How can i Pass constructor parameter in codeigniter via Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter file in controller . I want to pass parameter in constructor from ajax using jquery . How can pass value in $action ???

```
function __construct($action)
{
    $this->json['status']=false;
    if (preg_match("/json/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], $match))
        $this->requestType = "JSON";
    switch ($action) {
        case 'login': $this->login($_REQUEST);break;
        case 'addSocialPages': $this->setSocialLinks($_REQUEST);break;
        case 'get_info': $this->setSocialinfo($_REQUEST);break;
        case 'loginfromfront': $this->loginFront($_REQUEST);break;
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }
    if($this->requestType=="JSON")
        echo json_encode($this->json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do that.
The controllers are constructed by the core system and you cannot touch their constructor at initialization (core code: $CI = new $class(); // there is no parameter when called). The constructor is rather to initialize things not for do the hard work.

By the way your concept doesn't really make sense (to do everything in the constructor).

CodeIgniter has its own way to run/process requests, like this:

```
class Default extends CI_Controller {

    protected function send_json_output($response) {
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    public function login() {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        // your login code
        $response = array('succes' => true);
        $this->send_json_output($response);
    }
    public function get_info() {
        $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
        // your get_info code
        $user_name = $this->get_username_by_id($user_id);
        $response = array('username' => $user_name);
        $this->send_json_output($response);
    }
    public function login_from_front() {
        // your login_from_front code
    }


}
```

JS

```
// call the login action:
jQuery.post(
    '<?php echo site_url('default/login'); ?>',
    {username:'frank', password:1234},
    function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
            alert('You are logged in');
        }
    },
    'json'
);

// call the get_info action:
jQuery.post(
    '<?php echo site_url('default/get_info'); ?>',
    {user_id:123},
    function(data) {
        alert(data.username);
    },
    'json'
);
```